# parsing error in my code for some reason when trying to generate a message in javascript

Tags: javascript, void

i am trying to generate an random message but somehow there is a parsing error in my code that says that void is undefined even though it does not need to be defined,it calls it undefined

```
var a =1
while(a=1){
function alert(message?: any): void}
i have tried using 
GetFileDump=alert(GetFile AnyMessage)
//but that does not work either
//plz tell me what to do
```

Comment: what is this syntax?

Comment: my code i made for school

Comment: help me what should i do

Comment: That is not javascript.

Comment: What is GetFile and GetFileDump?

Comment: a cloud thing for files i use

Comment: `exp1 ? exp2 : exp3` is an operator and need 3 expressions for it to work, but one is missing and `message` and `any` are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = 1;
while (a === 1) {   // a = 1 is not the same as a === 1
  alert("message");
  a = 0;
}
```

Comment: its supposed to generate a random message with void

Comment: @codesforkids In javascipt, `void` is used like `void function test() { /*something*/}();`

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to use three comparison characters to compare a value, this is done to prevent different data types in comparing a value.